# Print a method with the help of object(which is dynamically created at run time in java)

Tags: java, object, dynamic, runtime

1. To make my question simple i am giving a simple scenerio fo example
   i have a `class A` and it has method `add()`.
2. now i want to `create its object` at run time `dynamically` just
   providing its `class name.` how can i do it, i have written the
   following code but ofcourse its not working.

   ```
    public class Practice{
    public void add(){
    System.out.println("add method");

    }
       public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

           String className = "A";
           Object xyz = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
           xyz.add();
           }}
   ```

The above code is not working i don't know why, i am unable to find where i am making mistake, and `second thing` in the **main mathod** i am **defing the object variable (which is xyz in above code) **, i want to c**reate object variable dynamically** too.

the above code of mine giving me the following error  is

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Practice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at practice.Practice.main(Practice.java:94)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Please define "not working". Are you getting any compilation error, exception at runtime, or incorrect output? Use [edit] option to clarify your question.

Comment: I see no `swing` elements here.

Comment: xyz is type of Object. It doesn't know about the type A

Comment: Do all the Objects have the same method (`add()`)?

Comment: on a sidenote, `public void add{` should be `public void add(){`

Comment: if thats the case you could create an interface, to which you then would cast the returning instance, and then execute that method

Comment: @notyou to make my question simple i use no swing component.

Comment: @Lino can you explain it with the help of code

Comment: Stacktrace you presented doesn't match code you posted. Anyway I suspect that you forgot to include information about package, so instead of `forName("A")` it should be `forName("full.package.name.of.A")`.

Comment: @Pshemo i want to tell my problem in simple way, its not the actual code which i write i am doing this work on swing, i want to just ask in simple way not making things complex by writting code of swing, as i feel it will be difficult for experts to understand that why i write a simple scenerio, make a edit in this, so it can work, and i will solve my problem in swing thanks :)

Comment: @shaunTait see the answer i posted

Comment: @shaunTait Trying to make your example as simple is possible is right choice, so congrats! But it is also important to (1) pay attention to not include problems which are unrelated to real question (to not waste time of people willing to help you which will also point out those unrelated problems) (2) make sure that example can be actually used to *reproduce* your problem. Those articles should be helpful with your future questions: [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thrown `ClassNotFoundException` indicates that the classloader could not find  the class for the given name. However this doesn't mean the class doesn't exist within the project. There is just a high chance that the stringdoes not match the full class name.

A classname does not only include the concrete name but also the packages.

Let's assume we have a class

```
package foo.bar;

public class Test
{
  public void shout() 
  {
    System.out.println( "Hello World" );
  }
}
```

so is the corresponding class name as a String: `"foo.bar.Test"` and not just simply `"Test"`.

---

Also when you instantiate an object with Reflection the returned type is Object and you stored it as one but by doing so you cannot access the methods of the class:

```
String clazzname = "foo.bar.Test";
try
{
  Object obj = Class.forName( clazzname ).newInstance();
  //compiler error because java.lang.Object does not contain a method shout()
  obj.shout();
}
```

But since we are certain that the returned Object is at least an instance of itself we should be able to safely cast it to the desired object:

```
String clazzname = "foo.bar.Test";
try
{
  foo.bar.Test obj = (foo.bar.Test)Class.forName( clazzname ).newInstance();
  // does work now since obj is now treated as a 'Test' object.
  obj.shout();
}
```

---

> I want to create object variable dynamically

Unfortunately that is not possible so you have to keep track of your instances in another way e.g. by storing them in an array or List or any other kind of collection.

Comment: Wao, you made my day , why you are so perfect in programming and i am not?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
public class A implements Foo
{
  public void add(){
    System.out.println("add method");

    }
}
```

Interface Foo defines methods in class A.

```
 public interface Foo
    {
      void add();
    }
```

How to call it.

```
public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException
  {
    String className = "A";
    Foo xyz = (Foo) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
    xyz.add();
  }
}
```

Comment: why we need the Interface Foo, can we do without it ?

Comment: Because we don't know about the methods provided in A class, using  interface solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices, depending on your usecase:

- When you have multiple classes with the same method, just create an `interface` containing that method and let all the other classes implement that said interface.
- When you also have a dynamic method, you can use `reflection`.

---

For the first case you can create an interface, in my case `Addable`:

```
public interface Addable{
    void add();
}
```

And then let all the classes, which may be created dynamically, implement that interface:

```
public class A implements Addable {
    public void add(){
        // logic
    }
}

public class B implements Addable {
    public void add(){
        // other logic
    }
}
```

In your main method you then can change the line of code from:

```
Object xyz = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

To:

```
Addable xyz = (Addable) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

---

For the second case with reflection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
     String className = "A";
     String methodName = "add";
     Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
     Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
     Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
     method.invoke(instance);
}
```

To elaborate what has been done:

- first load the class by name
- then get the method by the name
- create a new instance of that class
- invoke the method of that instance